# Use String id instead of ObjectId with MongoDataSource (apollo server)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, apollo-server, apollo-datasource

We have a MongoDB database using string ID's (no 12 bytes || 24 hex)
Theses ID's were generated by MeteorJS.

We now develop a GraphQL layer with apollo server.

We want to use the apollo-datasource-mongodb to load our data but when we call the findOnebyId method we got this error :

```
Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
    at new ObjectID (/app/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:59:11)
    at Function.ObjectID (/app/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:40:43)
    at file:///app/connectors/legacy.js:3:21
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:152:23)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:166:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
/app/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:59
```

It's because the module try to transform our string Id into a MongoDB ObjectId which is impossible with our current Id format.

After looking at the apollo-datasource-mongodb repo, it seems that it can handle string Id

```
    findOneById(
      id: ObjectId | string,
      options?: Options
    ): Promise<TData | null | undefined>
```

Source: https://github.com/GraphQLGuide/apollo-datasource-mongodb/blob/master/index.d.ts

Our Users dataSource:

```
import { MongoDataSource } from 'apollo-datasource-mongodb'

export class Users extends MongoDataSource {
}
```

The initiation (context layer):

```
Users: new Users(legacy.collection('users'))
```

The call (model layer):

```
async findOneById(obj, { id }, {dataSources: { Users }}) {
  return await Users.findOneById(id)
}
```

We don't use mongoose & typescript.

Is anyone has a idea to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

I found that is not compatible with string id.
More details can be found [here](https://github.com/GraphQLGuide/apollo-datasource-mongodb/issues/47#issuecomment-754748945)